# Can Line Geometry form a face in three.js?

Tags: three.js, geometry

I would like to create custom geometry using line in three.js .

Is it possible to create **face** using line (LineSegments) and color the face ?

Comment: you can create a face (`THREE.Face3()`) of a geometry (`THREE.Geometry()`) with vertices (`THREE.Vector3()`)

Comment: I have many sets of polyline-coordinates and I would like to draw it dynamically. I found it's difficult to define each of the faces(3 vertices to form a shape). Is there any way to draw a face using lines?

Comment: it's better to provide a jsfiddle or codepen to show what you've done already and what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: It's surprisingly hard to find an answer to this question. FWIW, I think there's plenty of info in that question. I think I've finally found the best starting point - THREE.Shape.
https://discourse.threejs.org/t/modeling-a-face-with-more-than-3-vertices/623/5